Retains the elements of the Vec specified by the predicate in parallel
Is it possible do Vec.retain() in parallel using rayon?
Here is the non-parallel code:
let mut vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
vec.retain(|&x| x % 2 == 0);

I expect the code like this:
use rayon::prelude::*;
let mut vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
vec.par_iter_mut().retain(|&x| x % 2 == 0); //can't work


retain is an inherent method of Vec, and not an iterator at all You could always compute a retainment bitmap in parallel then apply that, but the computation would need to be very expensive for that to be worth it.

As @Masklinn said, you can do that in parallel, but the effect will be negligible (if not slower) unless the heavy part is the filtering. If you just have a large Vec you want to filter, this won't be faster, since there will always need to be a final pass that removes the holes created.
